# Why is the application size in Add/Remove Programs increasing each time my app is uninstalled and reinstalled?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, addremoveprograms

It's a WiX MSI installer and each time I uninstall and reinstall it in my virtual machine environment the size reported in Add/Remove Programs gets bigger.  It's up to 200MB now when the installed files are only just over 30MB.  Any idea how this could happen and what I might be doing wrong?

Edit: Not using any custom actions, and I don't have anything for the uninstall, just assuming that WiX takes care of cleaning up after itself on uninstall, and it seems to.  From what I can see, it's the reported size that is incorrect, I can't find any duplicated files or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put your ARP entries ?  Also, how do you handle the RemoveOnuninstall attributs in the wix elements?

Do you have CustomActions that write data? Do you erase that data, when uninstalling ...

Fill in the most details as possible.

I found this post, then that will explain what's your situation [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg15656.html), and the link to [how the arp sized is calculated](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx) or almost ;)

Comment: From what your edit tells me you fall into the 2 links I just edited in.